# How to combine several rows into one row in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to find the total amount of associates at a company, as well as how many female and male engineers all in one query.

I am able to just get the sum of all associates on one row when that is the only thing that my query is looking for, but as soon as I try and combine it with the query looking for the number of males an females, the associate job titles start to separate.

My current code looks like this:

```
SELECT
    count(*) as [Number of Employees], Gender, Job
FROM 
    @table
WHERE 
    Job like '%Associate%'
GROUP BY grouping sets
    ((Job), (Gender))
```

the result sets have a row for each type of associate job, and I am trying to figure out how to combine them under one row under the name 'associate'

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
SELECT 
    count(*) as [Number of Employees],
    Gender, 
    JobTitle 
FROM 
    HumanResources.Employee 
WHERE 
    JobTitle like '%Engineer%' 
Group by grouping sets
    ((JobTitle), (Gender)) 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*)>=3
```

Comment: I do want all of the engineering jobs recorded, but to combine all titles into one single row and to be counted as the same

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for what you want 
You can try this because

```
SELECT SUM(a.[Number of Employees]) AS Value1, a.Gender , a.JobGroup FROM (
SELECT 'Engineer' AS JobGroup, COUNT(*) AS [Number of Employees], Gender, JobTitle FROM HumanResources.Employee WHERE JobTitle LIKE '%Engineer%' GROUP BY grouping sets ((JobTitle), (Gender))) a
GROUP BY a.Gender,a.JobGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this script. In addition, this will also return "Engineer" value in Job Title column for F & M. But if it is your requirement to have NULL there, some adjustment required in the script.

Note: Sub query is just for a better understanding. This can be also achieved in a single query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
GENDER,
JobTitle 
FROM
(    
    SELECT 
    JobTitle,
    Gender, 
    CASE 
        WHEN JobTitle like '%Engineer%' THEN 'Engineer'
        ELSE JobTitle
    END AS JobTitle
    FROM HumanResources.EmployeeFROM 
)A
WHERE A.JobTitle = 'Engineer' 
GROUP BY GENDER,JobTitle
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way

```
SELECT SUM(numberofemployees) AS total,
    Gender,
    CASE WHEN JobTitle LIKE '%Engineer%' THEN 'Engineer' ELSE JobTitle END AS JobTitle
FROM @table
GROUP BY Gender,
    CASE WHEN JobTitle LIKE '%Engineer%' THEN 'Engineer' ELSE JobTitle END
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
total   Gender  JobTitle
5       F       NULL
3       M       NULL
8       NULL    Engineer
```